# Spray: delete temporary file after response is sent

Tags: scala, spray

I use `getFromFile` to respond with temporary file. How can I delete this file after it's written to response stream? 
Underlying server is spray-servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution:

```
case class CleanupFile(file: java.io.File)

def sendFileAndCleanup(file: java.io.File) =
  mapRequestContext { ctx =>
    ctx.withRouteResponseMapped {
      case r: spray.http.HttpResponse => r.withAck(CleanupFile(file))
      case x => x
    }
  } {
    getFromFile(file)
  }
```

and then handle `CleanupFile` in the actor with `runRoute`:

```
def receive = runRoute(routes) orElse {
  case CleanupFile(file) => Try(file.delete())
}
```